# Getting ostream's Insertion Operators

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, wrapper, ostream

I have a class that I want to wrap an `ostringstream`. I've gone about it like this:

```
class Foo {
    ostringstream os;
public:
    template <typename T>
    decltype(ostream() << T(), Foo)& operator <<(const T& param) {
        os << param;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

My intent there is that I'd get any operator defined for `ostream` for free. But I'm getting the compilation error:

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template `unknown-type &Foo::operator <<(const T &)`

Am I using the `decltype` wrong or something?

Comment: Are you trying to use `decltype(ostream() << T(), Foo)` as SFINAE?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `Foo&` as the return type?

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean I'm not defining an alternate... but I do want an error in the calling code, not in my code if the user attempts to call a type that can't be inserted.

Comment: @RSahu I... I thought I was. That should be what the `decltype(ostream() << T(), Foo)&` evaluates to shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't understand the need to use `<<` inside of `decltype` at all.  Why not just use `Foo& operator <<(const T& param)` ? What are you trying to accomplish with such a complicated `decltype`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The error message when using an unsupported type became: `no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘Foo’ and ‘bork’` instead of `no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>’} and ‘const bork’`. Pretty nice imo.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That doesn't answer my question. What is the point of using `decltype(ostream() << T(), Foo)&` at all over just using `Foo&`? What is the `ostream() << T()` supposed to be accomplishing when the result will still be just `Foo`? To see if `ostream` has an `operator<<` for `T`? If so, seems like something that should be handled with `std::enabled_if` instead

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood. I can't manage to get that nice error if I use `Foo& there but the `decltype` works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Expression SFINAE is much easier to do with `decltype` than with `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: I would consider creating a type derived from `std::streambuf` for this, so that your `Foo` can actually be a `std::ostream` with all its functionality. Boost.Iostreams can help. A somewhat old but good article: http://gabisoft.free.fr/articles/fltrsbf1.html

Comment: This won't work for T without a default ctor, you need std::declval.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah I actually did that locally, just hacking together a toy example here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ostream` does not have a default constructor, and `Foo` is not an expression that can be used in `decltype`. Instead, you can directly use `os` in the first expression. In order to return `Foo&` easier I'd use a trailing return type and use `*this`.

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(const T& param) -> decltype(os << param, *this);
```

Comment: It's probably a problem with my architecture, but I can't seem to get this to handle `Foo() << endl`. I would have expected that to be supported? https://ideone.com/b6nYrY

Comment: @JonathanMee Well, `std::endl` is a function template - so in order for `Foo() << endl` to work, there needs to be a way for the compiler to select the correct instantiation of the function. The standard `std::ostream` has hard-coded overloads for manipulators (i.e `operator<<(std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&))`). If you want that to work you probably should do the same.

Comment: I think you are telling me that I also need to implement `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt` operators 10, 11, and 12 from this list. My question is why? These are just methods accepting function pointers right? Shouldn't that be defined in my template already?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, they are not already defined. The problem with `Foo() << endl` is *exactly* the same problem with `template<class T>void f(T); template<class>void g(); f(g);`. This will error because `g`, just like `std::endl`, is not a function, it is a function template which represents a *family* of functions. The compiler needs more information in order to instantiate `g` with the correct template arguments. You can manually do `Foo() << endl<char, char_traits<char>>` but this is quite ugly. So instead the `std::ostream` defines its own extraction operators with function pointers...

Answer (score 2):

This is purely based on [0x499602D2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2)'s answer and your link to the [missing overloads 10-12](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

I'm not sure what functions to use to test overload 11, but 10 and 12 are tested with `std::hex` and `std::endl`.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Foo {
private:
    std::ostringstream os{};

public:
    using char_type = std::ostringstream::char_type;
    using traits_type = std::ostringstream::traits_type;

    // generic, with perfect forwarding instead of "const T&"
    template<typename T>
    auto operator<<(T&& param) -> decltype(os << std::forward<T>(param), *this) {
        os << std::forward<T>(param);
        return *this;
    }

    // overload 10
    Foo& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&)) {
        func(os);
        return *this;
    }

    // overload 11
    Foo& operator<<(std::basic_ios<char_type, traits_type>& (*func)(
        std::basic_ios<char_type, traits_type>&)) {
        func(os);
        return *this;
    }

    // overload 12
    Foo& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char_type, traits_type>& (*func)(
        std::basic_ostream<char_type, traits_type>&)) {
        func(os);
        return *this;
    }

    auto str() { return os.str(); }
};

int main() {
    Foo a;

    a << "Hello Worl";      // generic
    a << std::hex << 13;    // 10 + generic
    a << std::endl;         // 12

    std::cout << a.str() << "\n";
}
```